# I can't get a Pubnub presence timeout to reliably use the heartbeat value - what am I missing?

Tags: pubnub

We have a variety of pubnub clients: javascript, ruby, actionscript

Its important that I know if/when clients leave a channel; even if a browser or desktop application (Native Air app) crashes. I'm updating the ActionScript library to support presence, so I cribbed from the JavaScript and Ruby implementations, I have presence working when everything is behaving nicely, but heartbeat doesn't appear to work in detecting clients that crash in my version.

So, I tried the following in Ruby using irb (gem version 3.6.7):

```
require 'pubnub'

pn = Pubnub.new(:subscribe_key => 'my_sub_key', :uuid => 'my_uuid', :heartbeat => 30)
pn.subscribe(:channel => 'my_channel') { |d| d.msg }
```

Then I entered the subscribe_key and channel into the Pubnub console. As expected, my subscription was there.

I exited out of irb and waited. I expected to see a presence timeout at about the 30 second mark, but needed to have to wait the entire 6 minutes before I received the timeout.

**Note also:** things do appear to work with the Javascript client.

Do I need to turn something else on beyond 'presence' to get this to work as expected, or am I misunderstanding what heartbeat does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the difference between what Javascript sets up and Ruby 3.6.7 I noticed that the Ruby heartbeat posts were not passing the heartbeat as a parameter.

When I added the heartbeat parameter to my ActionScript version, it began working as it should.

I'm still puzzled as to why the Ruby gem works for others though.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same test, using our web console at http://www.pubnub.com/console/?channel=my_channel&origin=pubsub.pubnub.com&sub=demo-36&pub=demo-36 (using the demo keys)

I ran your above code, then CTRL-D out of IRB.

And it works as expected, 30s after:

```
Fri Oct 31 2014 15:35:38:597 : <my_channel 
{"action":"timeout","timestamp":1414794938,"uuid":"my_uuid","occupancy":1}

Fri Oct 31 2014 15:35:08:527 : <my_channel> 
{"action":"join","timestamp":1414794908,"uuid":"my_uuid","occupancy":2}
```

Which version of the gem are you on? I just tested with 3.6.7 from RubyGems.

geremy

Comment: Bummer - I was using an older gem, so I got excited for a moment. No Joy though - I still get the same result. I've tried with different channels. Here's what I get: Sun Nov 02 2014 14:26:30:957 : <hello_world> {"action":"timeout","timestamp":1414956390,"uuid":"my_uuid","occupancy":1}
Sun Nov 02 2014 14:20:54:259 : <hello_world> {"action":"join","time

Comment: Shoot us an email at support@pubnub.com so we can dig deeper (get your keys, etc) to see why you are getting different results than us...

Comment: I've created a pull request on github

Comment: Please open a ticket as well, we'd like to discuss in more detail with you the specifics of whats going on...

Comment: A ticket was open, the latest fix to the gem @ master worked, the ticket has been closed.